# Sqlite3 - Get all rows after a given one with TEXT-values as PRIMARY KEYS

Tags: sql

I am facing a problem right now, where someone took TEXT-values as PRIMARY KEYS.

The table looks something like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|         ID          |     Order        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       "0004"        |      "0002"      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       "0009"        |      "0004"      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I need to write a query where only rows after a given one are returned.
Normally it would be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > id_number and order > order_number;
```

Yet i cannot figure out how to achieve the same thing with TEXT-values.
Trying something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > "id_number_as_string" and order > "order_number_as_string";
```

returns all rows in wrong order.

The goal is to prevent downloading the whole table from a remote server and to just get those which are not in the local table yet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code should work with strings.

Comment: Can you use CAST in your WHERE condition: WHERE CAST(ID as int) > X

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id > '0001' and order > '0002';
```

The comparison values should be strings, delimited by single quotes and padded with zeros.

Comment: I should have mentioned that also id like '0000023272' are possible. It's messy. But CASTING the ids to integers worked out very well. Thanks nevertheless!

Answer (score 1):

You have basically two options here:

1. Cast the ID's to INT and compare them as numbers.
2. Get the date of the last order, then only insert orders with a date bigger than the last inserted order date.